# How do I select particular column from executing reporting procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I select only particular column from a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[PositionsForNAV_PairTrades]
        @ComparePeriod = 'MTD',
        @OverrideCompareDate = '2010-12-31',
        @PortfolioId = '5',
        @OverrideStartDate = NULL,
        @NewPositionsOnly = 0,
        @ReportType = 0,
        @SourceID = 13,
        @SecurityType = 'Bond',
        @LongShort = 1
GO
```

It is giving me many columns, please help me how can I select only 3-4 particular columns from the result.

Comment: Please post the code for the procedure.

Comment: can't I do any modification when I try to execute it directly ? 
procedure code is too big in number :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use return values for this. A stored procedure has a single return value and it is used for error codes / status values, not data. It is also restricted to integers.

You need to either create a `#temp` table with the structure of the output to the stored procedure, then do:

```
INSERT #temp EXEC dbo.StoredProcedureName ...
SELECT col1, col2 FROM #temp;
```

Or you can use a variety of other hacks, like using `OPENQUERY` against a loopback provider (which I'm not even going to show because I think it's a bad idea).

For more ideas on sharing data between procedures, see:

http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html